# latexmk will compile in Sublime Text, even though the data is missing

Tags: latexmk, sublime-text

I've come across an odd problem. Here is what happens:

1. I run the Sublime Text builder using `⌘-B` on a *.tex* file. This file accesses external data from, say, *data.csv*.
2. If I now delete that same *data.csv* from my disk and run the builder once more, it will **compile anyway**.
3. After deleting the temporary files (using LaTeXTools' `⌘-C, Backspace` command), compiling will produce the expected error.

This behaviour occurs similarly when trying to use newly installed packages or including a *.pdf* through `\includegraphics`.

Also, (2) does not occur when I run `latexmk *.tex` from the Terminal.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I will simply comment instead of answer, because I'm not sure if this is correct. I suspect this is because `latexmk` builds a database of all the files necessary for compilation (see the `*.fdb_latexmk`). If the `.tex` document doesn't change, even if the external files change, `latexmk` gets tricked into saying "Nothing changed, no reason to recompile!" and doesn't do anything (hence no error). Once the aux files are removed `latexmk` says "Something has changed, better recompile" and runs into the error. Which plugin for Sublime Text do you use (LaTeXTools, LaTeXing)?

Comment: BTW do you have an actual question? :-) You can become more familiar with the usual format of questions by reading [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Welcome again!

Comment: @dartbirth, thanks for the answer provided. I went through the starter guide and - while trying to incorporate the insight you gave in your comment - it now stands as: "Can I make *Sublime Text 2* (with the *LaTeXTools* package installed) recompile, even though the internal file didn't change?".

Comment: I usually just remove the `*.fdb_latexmk` file and that forces it to take into account any changes in the folder.

Comment: Is there a way to automatically delete `*.fdb_latexmk` after a successful compilation?

Comment: Not as far as I know, and for similar reasons as the `*aux` files, I don't think you'd really want to anyways, you'd lose a lot of the functionality of `latexmk` :-)

Comment: Well, I'll just have to adapt to `latexmk`'s functionality then! Thanks for your answer @darthbith.

Comment: @darthbith When contents of an external file change, `latexmk` will generally do a recompilation.  However, there is an explicit exception that if the change is that the file no longer exists, then that by itself doesn't trigger a recompilation.  The reason is that normally there is no point doing a recompilation in this situation.  It's different if there's a custom dependency for the missing file; in that case `latexmk` will remake the missing file.

Comment: @JohnCollins Thanks for the clarification! I've also found that adding files that were previously missing (i.e. if I forgot to copy a jpeg file into the folder) also results in no recompilation. Is that expected?

Comment: @darthbith That's how `latexmk` works at present.  The information in the .log about a missing file is often just the base name without an extension or directory, so there are a lot of possibilities to be tested.  It would be worth while to improve `latexmk`'s behavior, at least for the common cases.  By the way, I've found that a convenient way to trigger a recompilation is just to make an innocuous change to the main .tex file, e.g., adding a space at an end of line.